# inArray() returns -1 even though element exists in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.post('service.php?getPhotos', function(data){ 

    var photoIds = [];

    $.each(data, function(){
        photoIds.push(this.id);
    });

    console.log(_photoId); //7962669392
    console.log(photoIds); //["7980686507", "7962669392", "7962163506"]
    console.log($.inArray(_photoId, photoIds)); //-1

});
```

Why doesnt `console.log($.inArray(_photoId, photoIds));` return `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

string vs integer I would imagine. Different types would mean that inArray does not see them as the same. Make sure you are using a string instead of an integer and this should work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `_photoId` is a number but `photoIds` contains strings. Try this:

```
$.inArray(''+ _photoId, photoIds)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `$.inArray` function also takes the type into account. It will not say that an integer is the same as a string. This is also explained in the first comment in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

You can use `_photoId.toString()` to get the string representation of the value.

Also note that ECMAScript (Javascript) have a native function called [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which does exactly the same thing as the jQuery one:

```
photoIds.indexOf(_photoId.toString())
```